# Setting the default site in horizon

Tags: horizon

Hey guys we have a multi site setup, when we open horizon it does not open the correct site.  Does anyone know where we can set the default site for horizon in sitecore 10.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about clicking on the icon on Launchpad:

1. Open `/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing/Horizon` item in `core` database
2. There is `PathResolver` field (that has value `Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.LaunchPad.HorizonHostResolver, Sitecore.Horizon.Integration`)
3. You can override this class and assembly to yours

The default logic of getting Horizon site looks in this way:

```
public virtual string Execute()
{
    string clientHost = _settings.Horizon().ClientHost;
    string clientHostStartPage = _settings.Horizon().ClientHostStartPage;
    string text = clientHost + clientHostStartPage;
    string text2 = _sitecoreContextHelper.Context.HttpContext?.Request.Url?.Host;
    string text3 = ((text2 != null) ? _siteManager.TryBestMatchClientSiteByHost(text2) : null);
    if (text3 != null)
    {
        return text + "?sc_site=" + text3;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Will it be able to set the required site in the Site DropDown at the top of the panel on Horizon Window?

Comment: Yes, you still will have that dropdown. You will set only the initial site.